# HTML5 Canvas moving object to mouse click position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouse, coordinates

Basically I want to move an object from point A ( 10x,10y ) to a position on the canvas where the mouse has been clicked ( 255x,34y ).

I'm currently using a method, but it goes from ++X then ++Y to coordinates; up then right.

I want it to go straight to position, likes an animation on a path. Slowing going from point A to Point B.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you “move” an object, what you really need to do is erase the object and redraw it

First code a function that will redraw the rect at a specified x,y

```
function draw(x,y){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle="skyblue";
    ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
    ctx.rect(x,y,30,20);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Then handle mousedown events and call the draw function

This example uses jquery for cross-browser compatibility, but you can always recode using native javascript.

```
// listen for all mousedown events on the canvas
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


// handle the mousedown event
function handleMouseDown(e){
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  $("#downlog").html("Down: "+ mouseX + " / " + mouseY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  draw(mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GHSG4/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    function draw(x,y){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle="skyblue";
        ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
        ctx.rect(x,y,30,20);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#downlog").html("Down: "+ mouseX + " / " + mouseY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      draw(mouseX,mouseY);

    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

    // start the rect at [10,10]
    draw(10,10);


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Click to redraw the rect at the mouse position</p>
    <p id="downlog">Down</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should have probably included that I need to object to move like an animation. Slowly approach the coordinates.

Comment: Ok, so modify the draw function to use requestAnimationFrame to gradually move the object toward the destination.  You will need to interpolate points on a line from your start to destination.  Here is a reference to requestAnimationFrame:  http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_HTML5_requestAnimationFrame_simple_example-19747.html  and here is a reference to interpolating points on a line:  http://snipplr.com/view/47206/

Comment: The abobe website seems to loading odd. But If it's not asking too much, could you possible put this into a play? I'm new to this kind of stuff. Looking at Interpolate Points on a Line, that seems to be what I'm looking at. The adobe animation part is something I already got figured out. I have the script on a setintervaul. Like I said, I have moving objects, but they move on a first X then Y basis. I need X & Y to run at the same time. Like a line straight to point A to point B.  Not up, then right to destination.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing the object being animated: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GHSG4/

Comment: nice, but is it possible, ori position (x0,y0), when user click on point A(x100,y100), then user click again point B(150,150) while the object is moving and current position is (x50,y50), then using this position (50,50) move to (150,150) instead 100,100 move to 150,150?