# Handle mouse down for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755991/html5-canvas-moving-object-to-mouse-click-position), I can get the mouse down handler to work perfectly.  But now I want to separate those functions into its own file called test.js.

In test.js, I have:

```
function handleMouseDown(e) {
    console.log('handleMouseDown');
}

function boardActivateMouse() {
    console.log('activateMouse ');
//    $(canvas).mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
//    $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);})
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});;
}

board.prototype.activateMouse = boardActivateMouse;
```

And in the calling html file, I have this:

```
<style>
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            console.log('window on load b4 mboard context ');
            mBoard = new board(context);
            console.log('window on load after mboard context ');
            mBoard.activateMouse();

        };
      </script>

    <canvas id="canvas" width=700 height=700></canvas>

</body>
```

In the console, I can see in the `"activateMouse "` message.  But the `handleMouseDown` function is not getting called at all?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain what board is / where it's defined ?

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: updated to jquery http://jsfiddle.net/cuuhC/1/ `board` is not defined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052310/jquery-assign-events-to-buttons/22052379#22052379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to use `on` JQuery method to catch event from DOM element dynamically created (not existing at the initialization in your case) :

In your file, paste the following code. It declares as anonymous function [self-invokated](http://www.davidyardy.com/davidyardy/blog/post/2013/07/14/JavaScript-Patterns-Self-invocation.aspx) when the page will be loaded. Obviously, you need to have loaded JQuery first :

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('mousedown',"#canvas",function(e){
        handleMouseDown(e);
    });
})(JQuery);
```

Comment: I know it has to do with the existing at the initialization and dynamically created, but could not pin down the proper syntax.  Thanks so lot.